# Laravel blade link does not work even though blade seems to have to value

Tags: hyperlink, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a link in Laravels blade. If I use this code, sure enough it displays the id.

```
{{ $photo->user->id }}
```

However, if I try to link to the users profile with this code, it does not work.

```
{{ link_to("users/$photo->user->id", 'Profile' ) }}
```

What is especially awkward about this is that I have a second link right below this one which looks like that and works fine.

```
{{ link_to("photos/$photo->id", $photo->title )}}
```

If anyone could help me out here this would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes in PHP only expand one level deep for variables (so $photo->user). You might want to consider using link_to_route() and then pass in the id instead.